# Labeling data with list of labels

Tags: plotting

I have three lists `a`, `b`, `c` and want to plot `c` versus `a` and show the corresponding `b` values in the plot.

I did the following:

```
a = {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1};

b = {0.5, 0.5, 4, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 
   4, 0.5, 1, 4, 4};

c = {277.94, 287.71, 529.02, 588.79, 913.11, 2856.6, 582.46, 3081.56, 
   3234.3, 1101.6, 516.34, 1409.8, 2517.8, 1874.5, 10320.5, 895.98, 
   3318.8, 20392.1, 25363.1};

data = Transpose[{a, c}];

ListPlot[data -> (StringJoin["b=", ToString[#]] & /@ b), 
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "c"}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}]
```

[image]

How can I achieve that **all** `data` points are labeled?

Comment: `Callout[] `?  ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Table[
  Callout[data[[i]], (StringJoin["b=", ToString[#]] & /@ b)[[i]], 
   After], {i, Length@data}], FrameLabel -> {"a", "c"}, Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}]
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Here is a workaround:

```
p1 = ListLogPlot[
  Table[Callout[
    data[[i]], (StringJoin["b=", ToString[#]] & /@ b)[[i]], 
    After], {i, 1, 19, 2}], FrameLabel -> {"a", "c"}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 11}, {100, 30000}}];

p2 = ListLogPlot[
  Table[Callout[
    data[[i]], (StringJoin["b=", ToString[#]] & /@ b)[[i]], 
    Before], {i, 2, 19, 2}], FrameLabel -> {"a", "c"}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 11}, {100, 30000}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}, Axes -> False];

Show[p2, p1]
```

[image]

There is still one point with overlay you need to fix.. You can change frame ticks  if you like to.

**Edit2:** I sorted data and change b accordingly but better to double check b values.

```
a = {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1};

b = {0.5, 0.5, 1, 4, 4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 
   0.5, 0.5, 4, 0.5};

c = {277.94, 287.71, 529.02, 588.79, 913.11, 2856.6, 582.46, 3081.56, 
   3234.3, 1101.6, 516.34, 1409.8, 2517.8, 1874.5, 10320.5, 895.98, 
   3318.8, 20392.1, 25363.1};

data = Transpose[{a, c}];
data = Sort@Transpose[{a, c}];

p1 = ListLogPlot[
   Table[Callout[
     data[[i]], (StringJoin["b=", ToString[#]] & /@ b)[[i]], 
     After], {i, 1, 6}], FrameLabel -> {"a", "c"}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10.5}, {200, 30000}}];

p2 = ListLogPlot[
   Table[Callout[
     data[[i]], (StringJoin["b=", ToString[#]] & /@ b)[[i]], 
     Before], {i, 7, 7}], FrameLabel -> {"a", "c"}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}];

p3 = ListLogPlot[
   Table[Callout[
     data[[i]], (StringJoin["b=", ToString[#]] & /@ b)[[i]], 
     After], {i, 8, 8}], FrameLabel -> {"a", "c"}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}];



p4 = ListLogPlot[
   Table[Callout[
     data[[i]], (StringJoin["b=", ToString[#]] & /@ b)[[i]], 
     Before], {i, 9, 19}], FrameLabel -> {"a", "c"}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}];



Show[p1, p2, p3, p4]
```

[image]

Comment: in this example, `ListLogPlot` will give better spacing than `ListPlot`

Answer (score 2):

One, albeit usually not ideal, method is to increase the size of your image:

```
a = {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1};

b = {0.5, 0.5, 4, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 
   4, 0.5, 1, 4, 4};

c = {277.94, 287.71, 529.02, 588.79, 913.11, 2856.6, 582.46, 3081.56, 
   3234.3, 1101.6, 516.34, 1409.8, 2517.8, 1874.5, 10320.5, 895.98, 
   3318.8, 20392.1, 25363.1};

data = Transpose[{a, c}];

ListPlot[data -> (StringJoin["b=", ToString[#]] & /@ b), 
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "c"}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}, ImageSize -> 4000]
```